# Kylo Azure AD integration

Tags: azure-active-directory, jaas, white-labelling, kylo

I am trying to add a plugin module in kylo for login into application using azure AD. We are facing challenge in redirecting the request to login page.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the redirect URI/reply URL in Azure matches whatever you have configured in your application code. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app

If you link the guide you are following and describe the redirect issue you are seeing, I can better assist.